# Space of weak$^*$-weak-continuous operators is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

In the book *Tensor Norms and Operator Ideals* by A. Defant and K. Floret, pg. 48, the authors use the fact that the subspace
$$Z = \{ T \in \mathcal{L}(X^*,Y) : T\; \text{is weak}^*\text{-weak-continuous} \}$$
is closed in $\mathcal{L}(X^*,Y)$. Here, $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ denotes the space of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ with the usual norm.

I've tried to prove this but found no success. Can somebody point me to a proof or reference of this fact? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which topology on $Y$ are you considering?

Comment: Each $T \in Z$ is continuous from $(X^*, \|\cdot \|)$ to $(Y, \|\cdot\|)$ and continuous from $(X^*, w^*)$ to $(Y,w)$, where $w^*$ and $w$ denote the weak$^*$ and weak topologies, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequence $\{T_n\}_n\subseteq Z$ converges to $T\in  \mathcal L(X^*, Y)$, we must to prove that $T$ lies in $Z$.  In order to do
this it is enough to show that, for every $y^*\in Y^*$, the linear functional
$$
  x^*\in  X^*\mapsto \langle T(x^*),y^*\rangle \in {\mathbb R}
  $$
is $w^*$-continuous.  This functional is clearly the norm limit of the functionals
$$
  x^*\in  X^*\mapsto \langle T_n(x^*),y^*\rangle \in {\mathbb R}
  $$
which are $w^*$-continuous since the $T_n$ lie in $Z$ by hypothesis.  The conclusion thus follows from the fact that the
$w^*$-continuous linear functionals on $X^*$ (aka the cannonical image of $X$) is closed in $X^{**}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!